# After Yom Kippur, are there regular weekday Maariv services?

Tags: yom-kippur, maariv

After one goes to shacharit, mincha, yizkor, n'ilah services on Yom Kippur, there is a festive meal in the form of a break-fast. Are there still normal weekday maariv services afterwards, and would it be after breaking the fast or before?

Comment: At Kevelson in Brooklyn in the 60's and 70's, there were no break fast meals but we still inserted Ma'ariv after the last of the 7 "H' hu -haelokim".  The ark would be closed, we would say Ma'ariv, then the tekiyah-gedolah was blown. This was not the order specified in Birnbaum, which my younger crown used, but we were told it was done to avoid people returning home without staying for the Ma'ariv minyan. I had/have no clue whether this custom was formalized in writings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a regular maariv after Yom Kippur, including *atah chontantanu* said in Shmoneh Esrei at the end of every Shabbat and Yom Tov. It is before the fast is broken, as havdalah must be said/heard before eating.

Source: [Shulchan Aruch OC 624 and Mishnah Berurah there](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.624?lang=en&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.624.1&lang2=en).

Comment: Re "It [_maariv_] is before the fast is broken": in the Orthodox synagogue in which I prayed this year, they recited _havdala al hakos_ after _n'ila_, then most of the women left to eat some food provided by the synagogue while the men and some women said _maariv_.

Comment: This is actually a Machloket. It's very possible Maariv after Yom Kippur is just a Minhag.

Comment: There is no reason Maariv needs to be said before the fast is broken.